# Array of int or vector?

Tags: c++

i'm trying to store some elements that is going to change every time, but i don't know which

way is better and why. I'm thinking about two ways, 1) declaring array of int and loop or

use vector's.

Which way is better and why?

Does declaring array of int have any future memore problems as leak?

the code down below show the two ways i'm talking about:

1)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{

     int x[5];

     x[0] = 10;
     x[1] = 20;
     x[2] = 30;
     x[3] = 40;
     x[4] = 50;


for(unsigned int i = 0;i<=sizeof(x[5]); i++)
    {


     std:: cout << "x[" << i << "] = "<< x[i] << std::endl;

}

system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{

    std::vector<int> x;

    x.push_back(10);
    x.push_back(20);
    x.push_back(30);
    x.push_back(40);
    x.push_back(50);


for(unsigned int i = 0;i<=x.size()-1; i++)
    {


     std:: cout << "x[" << i << "] = "<< x[i] << std::endl;

}

system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(x[5])`. I'm curious what lead you to this unusual expression.

Comment: @Joe, `x[5]` is not evaluated, so it's fine. That said, it's still a bit odd.

Comment: That is right i was looking for sizeof(x), but could't avoid the typo. lol

Comment: @Joe I. the argument of `sizeof()` is not evaluated, no UB. He was also not looking for either one. He was looking for `sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])`.

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz No, as I just mentioned, `sizeof(x)` is wrong, you want `sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is all you have to do, and your array will always have a size that is known at compile time, then you do not need `std::vector`.

On the other hand, in C++11 you could use `std::array` instead of a plain C array (`std::array` is a zero-overhead, safer and more functional wrapper over a C array):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
     std::array<int, 5> x = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
     //                           ^^^^^^^^
     {
         std:: cout << "x[" << i << "] = "<< x[i] << std::endl;
     }
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24446). Notice, that `std::array` offers a `size()` member function which you may want to use instead of the `sizeof` operator.

Moreover, since `std::array` is a standard sequence container, you could iterate through its element this way:

```
 std::size_t i = 0;
 for (auto e : x)
 {
     std:: cout << "x[" << i++ << "] = "<< e << std::endl; 
 }
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24447).

Comment: Safer and more functional :)

Comment: @chris: I quoted you :) Thanks

Comment: And this won't cause any future memory leak?

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz: No, it will not. You are not allocating any object dynamically, so there is no way this could cause memory leaks.

Comment: I'm asking this, becouse once i tried to declare array of int as the code above, but got some weird memory leaks in my program

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz: If you did `int* x = new int[5]`, then you could have created memory leaks. But if you create an array as above (`int x[5]`), then there is no dynamic allocation - and no memory leaks. However, you can only do this if the size of the array is known at compile-time. If it is not, use `std::vector`.

Comment: Well because of the good explanation, code simple and having most vote. You deserve your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

If the size is known at compile time, use `std::array`. If not, use `std::vector`. In either case, use iterators to look at the elements:

```
typedef std::array<int> my_container_type;
typedef my_container::iterator iterator;
my_container_type my_container = { whatever };

for (iterator it = my_container.begin(); it != my_container.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << "x[" << (it - my_container.begin()) << "] = " << *it << '\n';
```

By using iterators you greatly reduce the risk of accidentally using a loop limit like `sizeof(x[5])`, which is nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

Neither is "better". They both address entirely different use cases.

If you know the array size at compile time and are 100% sure it will never change, sure, use a plain old array. It has less overhead, and the compiler can even aid you with static analysis by spotting any attempts to read outside the boundaries.

On the other hand, if you are unsure of the array's side (i.e. you will be reading input from a file or the user), then use the `std::vector`. It can grow to any size to meet your needs.