# when to use a vector instead of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I don't really understand when you would need to use vectors. Could someone please give me an example of when you should decide to use a vector instead of an array, thanks.

Comment: Try writing leak-free, exception-safe code for dealing with dynamically-sized C-style arrays that are created in, returned from and passed around between various functions that don't know of each other.  Make copies of the arrays and insert / delete elements at random positions.  Then try writing the same code using `std::vector`.  If you don't have time for doing this: have a look at [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046823/array-of-int-or-vector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage is dynamic memory allocation.
A vector starts with limited size, and doubles its size when more space is needed. The average insert complexity is still O(1), which is the main gain here. It's still a bit slower than arrays though.

Other than that, everything you do with a vector can be done with arrays. However, vectors are easier to use, since they can have iterators and fancy constructors and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are fixed size. When you allocate an array, it contains n elements. If you need to add the (n+1)th element, you have to allocate a new array, copy over all of the old elements, and then add the (n+1)th element. Using a vector, this all is taken care of for you. The vector keeps an array as storage and keeps track of how many elements are present. If the array backing the vector runs out of space, the vector has to do allocate a new larger array, copy over the old elements, and then add the one element. But this is already implemented for you, and you don't have to reimplement it every time you need an array that grows.

There are also advantages in abstraction when creating more complicated data structures. The vector is a class, while the array is not.